# Simplify code and reduce join statements in pyspark data frames

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have a data frame in `pyspark` like below.

`df.show()`

```
+---+-------------+
| id|       device|
+---+-------------+
|  3|      mac pro|
|  1|       iphone|
|  1|android phone|
|  1|   windows pc|
|  1|   spy camera|
|  2|   spy camera|
|  2|       iphone|
|  3|   spy camera|
|  3|         cctv|
+---+-------------+


phone_list = ['iphone', 'android phone', 'nokia']
pc_list = ['windows pc', 'mac pro']
security_list = ['spy camera', 'cctv']

from pyspark.sql.functions import col

phones_df = df.filter(col('device').isin(phone_list)).groupBy("id").count().selectExpr("id as id", "count as phones")
```

`phones_df.show()`

```
+---+------+
| id|phones|
+---+------+
|  1|     2|
|  2|     1|
+---+------+


pc_df = df.filter(col('device').isin(pc_list)).groupBy("id").count().selectExpr("id as id", "count as pc")
```

`pc_df.show()`

```
+---+---+
| id| pc|
+---+---+
|  1|  1|
|  3|  1|
+---+---+

security_df = df.filter(col('device').isin(security_list)).groupBy("id").count().selectExpr("id as id", "count as security")
```

`security_df.show()`

```
+---+--------+
| id|security|
+---+--------+
|  1|       1|
|  2|       1|
|  3|       2|
+---+--------+
```

Then I want to do a full outer join on all the three data frames. I have done like below.

```
full_df = phones_df.join(pc_df, phones_df.id == pc_df.id, 'full_outer').select(f.coalesce(phones_df.id, pc_df.id).alias('id'), phones_df.phones, pc_df.pc)

final_df = full_df.join(security_df, full_df.id == security_df.id, 'full_outer').select(f.coalesce(full_df.id, security_df.id).alias('id'), full_df.phones, full_df.pc, security_df.security)
```

`Final_df.show()`

```
+---+------+----+--------+
| id|phones|  pc|security|
+---+------+----+--------+
|  1|     2|   1|       1|
|  2|     1|null|       1|
|  3|  null|   1|       2|
+---+------+----+--------+
```

I am able to get what I want but want to simplify my code.

```
1) I want to create phones_df, pc_df, security_df in a better way because I am using the same code while creating these data frames I want to reduce this.
2) I want to simplify the join statements to one statement
```

How can I do this? Could anyone explain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way using `when.otherwise` to map column to categories, and then `pivot` it to the desired output:

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df.withColumn('cat', 
    F.when(df.device.isin(phone_list), 'phones').otherwise(
    F.when(df.device.isin(pc_list), 'pc').otherwise(
    F.when(df.device.isin(security_list), 'security')))
).groupBy('id').pivot('cat').agg(F.count('cat')).show()

+---+----+------+--------+
| id|  pc|phones|security|
+---+----+------+--------+
|  1|   1|     2|       1|
|  3|   1|  null|       2|
|  2|null|     1|       1|
+---+----+------+--------+
```

Comment: Just a small doubt here if I want to do a average of devices in last 10 days for each `id` how can i do that. The `df` has records for last `10` days